# Backspace not working in scala prompt under cygwin

Tags: windows, scala, cygwin, command-prompt

I am using `cygwin` on Windows 7 to work on `Scala` but backspace doesn't work on `Scala` prompt. I tried backspace on `Scala` on Windows command prompt it works fine. I tried backspace in `cygwin` prompt itself it work fine there too.

So is there any setup I need to do to make it work?

Comment: Try one of the solutions here: http://superuser.com/questions/354715/backspace-does-not-work-in-cygwin cygwin doesn't play well with most programs and backspace